# Get Sum Of Distinct Values from List in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have a list named Cart_Items and it is populated when user press Add To Cart Button. The list has objects ItemID and Quantity.
i need to get the total quantity of an item from this list. As there are different items in the list i can't get the total quantity of a specific item.
if i use sum(function) it returns the sum of all the quantities.
And what i am trying to achieve is that if there are more than one record of same item then get the SUM of that specific item's quantity.
here is the class structure:

```
Public Class CartItem
Private m_ItemId As Integer
Public Property ItemId() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_ItemId
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        m_ItemId = value
    End Set
End Property

Private m_Quantity As Integer
Public Property Quantity() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_Quantity
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        m_Quantity = Value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

List:

```
ItemId      Quantity
1            5
3            6
1            2
1            6
4            8
```

so i want to get Total Quantity of ItemId = 1 that should be 13.

so What would be the best way to get the total quantity for specific itemId?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, filter the items with a given criteria which in this case is `CartItems` that have an `itemId` of `1`. Then select all the quantities and apply `distinct` to remove the duplicated values and lastly `sum` the result.

```
Dim result As Integer = (From item In myList
                         Where item.ItemId = 1
                         Select item.Quantity).Distinct().Sum()
```

Comment: This will return wrong result in case list contains two items with same id and same quantity value.

Answer (score 2):

You need group all items by theirs `Id`, the calculate sum of `Quantity` for every group.

```
var itemTotals = myList.GroupBy(Function(item) item.ItemId)
                       .Select(Function(group)
                                  Return New With
                                  {
                                      .ItemId = group.Key,
                                      .Quantity = group.Sum(Function(item) item.Quantity)
                                  }
                               End Function)
                       .ToList()
```

So you will get collection of anonymous objects with all items in the `myList` and their total quantities.

```
{ .ItemId = 1, Quantity = 13 }
{ .ItemId = 3, Quantity = 6 }
{ .ItemId = 4, Quantity = 8 }
```

Instead of anonymous types you can use your `CartItem` class because it have same properties in same context. So `Select` pert will look like this:

```
.Select(Function(group)
            Return New CartItem With
            {
                .ItemId = group.Key,
                .Quantity = group.Sum(Function(item) item.Quantity)
            }
        End Function)
```